# Why won't Gradle find my locally published plugin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have one project which contains and publishes a Gradle plugin:

```
plugins {
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    `kotlin-dsl`
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31"
    `maven-publish`
}

project.group = "com.company.gradle"
project.version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins.create("pomPlugin") {
        id = "com.company.gradle.pom"
        implementationClass = "com.company.gradle.pom.PomPlugin"
    }
}
```

Building this and publishing (via `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`) succeeds without errors. After it completes, my local maven repo `~/.m2/reposiory` contains:

```
./com/company/
./com/company/gradle
./com/company/gradle/pom
./com/company/gradle/pom/maven-metadata-local.xml
./com/company/gradle/pom/1.0.0
./com/company/gradle/pom/1.0.0/pom-1.0.0.jar
./com/company/gradle/pom/1.0.0/pom-1.0.0.module
./com/company/gradle/pom/1.0.0/pom-1.0.0.pom
./com/company/gradle/pom/com.company.gradle.pom.gradle.plugin
./com/company/gradle/pom/com.company.gradle.pom.gradle.plugin/maven-metadata-local.xml
./com/company/gradle/pom/com.company.gradle.pom.gradle.plugin/1.0.0
./com/company/gradle/pom/com.company.gradle.pom.gradle.plugin/1.0.0/com.company.gradle.pom.gradle.plugin-1.0.0.pom
```

Then I have another project that tries to use the plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    id("com.company.gradle.pom") version "1.0.0"
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
```

but Gradle cannot resolve the plugin:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'com.foxit.gradle.pom', version: '1.0.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.foxit.gradle.pom:com.foxit.gradle.pom.gradle.plugin:1.0.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this at the top of your `settings.gradle` file in the project where you want to use your plugin.

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
```

The `gradlePluginPortal()` bit is for "real" gradle plugins which have been published.

The `mavenLocal()` bit is for your locally published plugins.

The repositories blocks you have in the `build.gradle` are for dependencies and not plugins.

Comment: so the `buildscript` block is not for the build script? Nice.

Comment: Yeah not sure why it's this way but it complains if the `pluginManagement` block isn't in settings.